# How do I use Google Chrome instead of Chromedriver Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

Since chromedriver cannot remember searches history nor does it save cookies... I want to use GoogleChrome, my original browser in Python Selenium, because I want to bypass Hcaptcha, and I have everything set in my original browser to do so.

Answers are very much appreciated, I am quite new to this so please write in details so that I can understand and show me how to do stuff, much love! :)

Comment: Hcaptcha is built specifically to stop people writing scripts for websites such as you seem to be doing. Try searching for an API for what you want or consider using a different service. Also this question should include any code you've trued and errors you've encountered from your own research and attempts before asking here - this isn't a discussion forum!

Answer (score -4, accepted):

did you specify your driver?
if not this might help :)

from selenium import webdriver

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

Comment: also there's a problem whenever I write "driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/") it doens't work whatsoever just directs me to the main page of google.com, how do I fix it? because I also need to use this command driver.find_elements_by_xpath

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by providing your chrome profile to the selenium.

First type this into your chrome address bar `chrome://version/` and copy the profile path.

> Note :- Remove the Default from the path i.e. if the path is **/home/aditya/.config/google-chrome/Default** then after removing the Default, the path will be
> **/home/aditya/.config/google-chrome**

then paste the profile path into the following code :-

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=/home/aditya/.config/google-chrome") # profile path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for commenting! I've did everything as told here, and this is what I got: https://ibb.co/mGPgVQf I'd be very glad if you'd say what I am doing wrong :)

Comment: also there's a problem whenever I write "driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/") it doens't work whatsoever just directs me to the main page of google.com, how do I fix it? because I also need to use this command driver.find_elements_by_xpath

Comment: Copy paste this code and see if it is working or not :- https://notepad.pw/share/o2duut9qs

Comment: Doesn't work "ile "c:\Users\noah.REDIL\Desktop\New folder\codeblocks.py", line 17
    options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\Users\noah.REDIL\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data") # profile path
                                                                                                  ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 16-17: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape"